# Why precision problems in a floating point number varies according to values?

Tags: c++, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I was wondering why precision problems in floating point numbers are different with different values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

 int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);

        double d1(1.0);
        std::cout << d1 << std::endl;

        double d2(0.1);
        std::cout << d2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
  }
```

The output of this program is:

1. 1
2. 0.10000000000000000555

If both the numbers are of type double (that generally have precision problems), why compiler doesn't find any problem with value 1.0 and does find a problem with value 0.1. One more thing that it not clear to me is that if precision is set to 20 digits, why do I get a number that contains 21 digits as the result of d2?

Comment: Some numbers can be expressed exactly in binary floating point format, other numbers can only be approximated. Have a read through the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) to see how things work under the hood.

Comment: However, when you see `1` and it's a double or float, never assume it's *exactly* 1; always use floating point "logic" when e.g. comparing.

Comment: @Evert: You managed to pick one of the two exceptions. _Exactly_ 1.0 and _exactly_ 0.0 do show up unusually often.

Comment: @MSAlters True, but it's more a general note of caution; at least I still wouldn't trust 1.0 to be 1.0 if it's printed. I've come across `value == 0.0` comparisons, which were mostly to test whether `value` had been set to something else than its default value. Not sure/curious about cases for `value == 1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer uses a representation of floating point in which `1.0` can be stored exactly, but `0.1` can't. This is probably [IEC 60559](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Leading zeroes are not considered part of the precision (they are just placeholders); your output does actually have 20 digits not counting the `0.` on the start.